# How would I reduce an object of string:bool pairs into a single array of 'true only' strings?

Tags: underscore.js

Let's say I have an object like this:

```
{ "foo" : true, "bar" : false, "gob" : true, "lob" : false }
```

and I wanted to reduce it to an array of the string keys that have an associated true value:

```
[ "foo", "gob" ]
```

How would I do this using underscore?

Comment: Why the need to use Underscore for something that can be done with vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: @JustinNiessner not really a need, but that's what the question is, otherwise I already know how :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var o = { "foo" : true, "bar" : false, "gob" : true, "lob" : false }
var result = [];
_.each(o, function(value, key) {
  if (value) result.push(key);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Kinda weird saying 'you don't need underscore', then using `_.each`. )

Comment: @raina77ow _.each can be easily replaced with for in. I meant "I am using it since you asked"..Updating that one since it felt wierd to you..:)

Comment: Of course, but then you'll have to use `.hasOwnProperty` or something like this. My point is that `underscore` and its similars are very convenient: they go out your way when the browser do support corresponding ES5 functions, but will save you a lot of time writing your own shims for IE8 and similars.

Comment: Absolutely Right..Agreed

Answer (score 5):

One possible approach:

```
var obj = { "foo" : true, "bar" : false, "gob" : true, "lob" : false };
var res = _.filter(_.keys(obj), function(k) { return obj[k]; });
console.log(res); // ['foo', 'gob']
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6PZTa/). In other words, we collect all the keys of the given object, then filter out the ones with corresponding values being falsy.

---

Alternative (reduce-based):

```
var res = _.reduce(obj, function(memo, v, k) { 
  if (v) {
    memo.push(k);
  }
  return memo;
}, []);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/R6N7s/). It's more complex as a code, but it walks through the collection just once.

Comment: Yes, I like the reduce idea--and you beat me by a couple seconds :).

Comment: I think your answer is the best, but due to my own limitations I chose to use blunderboy's because it was easier for me to convert to coffeescript... it's kinda meta but: am I suppose to select the answer that I used or the answer that the seemed the best and got the most upvotes?

Answer (score 0):

```
_.chain(obj)
 .pairs()
 .filter(function(pair){return pair[1]})
 .keys()
 .uniq()
 .value()

// ["foo","gob"]
```

GG